# Keycloak token claim value of "iss" is using internal IP when auth through Nginx

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Keycloak server behind a Nginx,

when we do a login request:

```
curl --location 'https://internal-ip-of-keycloak/auth/realms/demo1/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=rest-client' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=user1' \
--data-urlencode 'password=pass1'
```

The JWT token's "iss" value is "internal-ip-of-keycloak"

Our Nginx config about the headers is as follows:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;                                
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                    
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;    
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;                            
proxy_set_header X-Request-ID $request_id;
```

Thanks a lot!

In my keycloak deployment, I have the following

```
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
```

but it seems that does not help. Is there something like
KEYCLOAK_SERVER_NAME to force Keycloak to use public domain name in the "iss"?

Comment: Have you seen this Keycloak page: https://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname?

Comment: Hi Codo, thank you. I think it should work! Great findings.